# Apache gives 403 forbidden

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

I recently had to reinstall Ubuntu and everything else as my SSD crashed.

I've got Apache/MySQL/PHP set up and can access localhost/ without problems. Running PHP and MySQL works fine as well.

I keep my projects in a Dropbox folder (since the crash) located at `/home/powerbuoy/Dropbox/Projects/` and have set up VHOSTs that point to some of the projects in there. I've also set up `/etc/hosts` so that I can access my projects through `http://project-name.dev`.

However, when I try to visit `http://any-project.dev` all I get is `403 forbidden`. I've run `chmod -R 777 Projects/` and all the files and folders are now green in the terminal. That didn't help.

I checked the error-logs and they say:

```
[crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/powerbuoy/Dropbox/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

But there isn't even supposed to be a `.htaccess` file anywhere there.

I even set up a completely empty project (`/home/powerbuoy/Dropbox/Projects/test/index.php` with just `<?php phpinfo()` inside), set up a VHOST and a `http://test.dev` URL. I get the same error here.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: I tried moving my test project to the desktop (`/home/powerbuoy/Desktop/test/`) and now it works :P

Perhaps it has something to do with the projects being located inside the Dropbox folder??

Comment: chown to www-data? or whatever name your apache process runs under.

Comment: Ok but wouldn't `chmod 777` allow _anything_ to access everything?

Comment: It would in theory, but sometimes that isn't enough.
It could be that the dropbox doesn't allow it because of user permissions etc...

Comment: Ok, I've honestly never run `chown` but is it just `chown www-data Projects/` or? Also - see my updated question: moving the folders outside the Dropbox folder seems to solve it.

Comment: try `man chown` it should give you all the info....

Comment: Try reloading Apache.

Comment: I've reloaded it several times during the setup. Also, I noticed the problem. I had to `chmod` the directories higher up in the tree. /home/powerbuoy/ and up had to be 755. It works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently simply `chmod`ing the directory the project is in wasn't enough. I had to `chmod` all the directories higher up in the tree as well.

So even though my VHOST pointed to `/home/powerbuoy/Dropbox/Projects/AProject/` simply `chmod`ing `/AProject/` is not enough but it has to be done all the way from `/home/powerbuoy/` it seems.

Answer (score 8):

Most probably this is a chmod issue. You must change all trees chmod settings. If you have ssh access you can try this commands:

```
chmod 755 $(find /home/user/public_html -type d)
chmod 644 $(find /home/user/public_html -type f)
```

Please replace /home/user/public_html part to 'your real path'.

Comment: `chmod 755 $(find /home/user/public_html -type d)`
works fine for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason you had to chmod the permission going up the directory tree is that Linux doesn't permit you to simply access a folder such as `/home/jsmith/my_folder` directly. You have to also have execute permissions to  `/` `/home/` and `/home/jsmith` . The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories within it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Since I didn't chmod /home/ I assume that's already available then?

Comment: I believe you're correct. /home usually has 755 by default I believe, however, you'll need to ensure +x is configured for powerbuoy/Dropbox/Projects/ and onwards. Perhaps,do a chmod -R ugo+x powerbuoy (this will recursively add these permissions down the tree)